# Can a List<MyClass> object be used as data for a locally processed ReportViewer Report?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I want to print a table of values using ReportViewer in local processing mode. The table will have a fixed number of columns, and a variable number of rows. The data will come from a List of my custom class. Now when I create a blank Report in my project, and add a table (tablix) to display the data, it asks me to add a DataSet. But I don't have a DataSet to add as I want to use a List of my custom class in code to populate the data, so I cancel the DataSet wizard. But if I leave off the DataSet it gives me an error "The tablix ‘Tablix1’ is in the report body but the report has no dataset.  Data regions are not allowed in reports without datasets." Can I use a List of my custom class as the data for a Report? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There is already a question on SO describing this process, so I have marked your question as a duplicate. You can find a link to the other question at the top of your post. If, for some reason, the solutions posted there don't work, feel free to come back and extend your question.

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks! I searched and searched before posting, but obviously I am not as good at it as you are. That answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry about your searching skills: It's always easier to find if you already know the answer (you can't google for "object data source" unless you know that this is what it's called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251784.aspx

- Add a report to the project using the Report Wizard
- From the Project menu, select Add New Item.
- In the Add New Item dialog, select Report Wizard. Type a name for the
  report and click Add.
- This launches the Report Wizard with the Data Source Configuration
  Wizard.
- In the Choose a Data Source Type page, select Object and click Next.

**In the Select the Data Objects page, expand the class hierarchy under BusinessObject until you see Product in the list. Select Product and click Finish.**

- You now return to the Report Wizard. Notice that the new data source object is added to your project in Solution Explorer.
- In the Dataset Properties page, in the Data source box, verify that global is selected.
- In the Available datasets box, verify that Product is selected.
- Click Next.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your link is exactly what I wanted.  I had no idea Microsoft called a custom class a "Business Object".